# How to duplicate a record with your relationships in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I've tried several things I've searched for on the web but I still haven't had success, there's a lot of content for previous versions of Laravel, but for 8 I haven't found it.

I tried to do this, but without success.

```
    public function DuplicateList($idList)
    {
        $getList = Accompaniment::with(['categoryAccompaniments', 'categoryAccompaniments.additionals'])->find($idList);
        $newList = $getList->replicate();
        $newList->push();

        foreach($getList->categoryAccompaniments as $categoryAccompaniment)
        {
            $newList->categoryAccompaniments()->attach($categoryAccompaniment);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you duplicate 1 record with all your relationships in Laravel 8

```
public function DuplicateList($idList)
    {
        $getList = Accompaniment::with(['categoryAccompaniments', 'categoryAccompaniments.additionals'])->find($idList);
        $newList = $getList->replicate();
        $newList->save();
        $getCategories = $getList->categoryAccompaniments->toArray();
        $newList->categoryAccompaniments()->createMany($getCategories);
    }
```

Comment: Important to say that you need to add the `$fillable` property in all relationships model.